# How to a submit button to email contents of page (form)

Tags: html

I am trying to set up a new website and have a contact page with a submit button. This should then email the contents of fields completed to an email address.

**Here is the code**

Maths Question: 9 + 3 = ?

```
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input type="text" name="user_answer" class="contact" /><input type="hidden" name="answer" value="4d76fe9775" /></p></div>
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p style="padding-top: 15px"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="Send"<a href="mailto:driveoffuk@gmail.com"></a>
      </p></div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can not do this using HTML alone; you need a server-side language such as PHP, Java, or C#.

Comment: I see a mailto, do you mean to open an email client and would like the user to send that email ?

Comment: you can also attain this using jquery ajax.... and let the php `mail()` do the trick. =)

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means valid html. What you're going for could be this:

```
<form action="mailto:driveoffuk@gmail.com">
    <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p>
         <input type="text" name="user_answer" class="contact" />
         <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="4d76fe9775" />
    </p></div>
    <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p style="padding-top: 15px">
         <input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="Send" />
    </p></div>
</form>
```

This will though only open the email up in the browsers email client. If you want to actual send an email, then you have to send a request to a server and make the server send an email.